# Updating all bands of PostGIS raster in one function (like st_setvalues) with one geomval[] set?

Tags: postgis, raster, multi-band

I have ~700 raster tables in postgres. Some have an expanse the size of California. All the tables are tiled and share tile IDs.

Given a [`geomval`](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.1/geomval.html) set, I need to make updates to each table. Here, I currently make use of [`st_setvalues`](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.1/RT_ST_SetValues.html) (specifically variant 5), but I have to loop through each table to make those changes.

To speed this process (which can be quite slow, depending on the size of the geomval set), I'm thinking of making these individual tables as bands in one single table.

Does there exist a way to quickly update all bands at once so that I don't have to run the spatial intersection multiple times?

Currently, `st_setvalues` only operates on a one band at a time.

Comment: I guess you will have to write your own variant of St_SetValues()...

Comment: @Pierre, can you put that as an answer and expand a bit on why. You are someone who knows a lot about PostGis raster capabilities and it can be hard to find information, which is a shame, as it is very powerful

Comment: Very good/useful question.

Answer (score 1):

You could write your own PL/pgSQL variant of ST_SetValues() taking an array of array of values (one array of values per band) instead of a band number. The function would iterate over the bands, using the single band ST_SetValues() functions to set the values. You would end up with 4 variants corresponding to the 4 ST_SetValues() functions taking a band number.